# How do you move SSL to non-SSL? [ Wordpress 4.6.1 + CiviCRM 4.7.14]

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I responded to a question re: using Let's Encrypt SSL certs at [this comment](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/has-lets-encrypt-been-put-into-production-with-civicrm/16283#16283). I now need to go in the other direction because I made a mirror of our live site on my laptop in an xampp environment (win 10). There I don't have, nor do I want to use, an SSL certificate.

First, I removed the https redirect in .htaccess. Then, I was able to "simply" deactivate the Really Simple SSL plugin by following https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/uninstall-websitebackend-not-accessible. This made our local Wordpress site work and I could also get into the back-end. However, CiviCRM does not work from either the back-end or front-facing pages. From the back-end, it generates an error trying to bring up the CiviCRM dashboard. Both give the same error:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\vhost\sdbikecoalition\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\civicrm.settings.php on line 450"

[edit] And, of course, I checked the civicrm.settings.php file and found nothing suspicious [/edit]

I suspect it is because, on our live SSL site, I went to Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs and checked Yes on "Force Secure URLs (SSL)". Is there somewhere I can change this by just directly editing a record in the CiviCRM MySQL database?

I suspect that will solve my issue as that was the only thing I did within CiviCRM that was specific to SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify the file which is being reported as having a syntax error. PHP has a syntax check mode with `-l` (for "lint").

```
php.exe -l C:\vhost\sdbikecoalition\wp-content\uploads\civicrm\civicrm.settings.php
```

If `civicrm.settings.php` is not valid PHP, CiviCRM will not function - SSL or no SSL.

Note that your local PHP install may differ in version and therefore syntax from the PHP installed on your server.

Comment: Chris - Thank you for your observation. I was barking up the wrong tree. When I edited the BASEURL, I fat-fingered a right bracket } into the trash. Once fixed, I received an error indicating I had forgotten to also change civicrm_root to my local directory and then I was up and running! I then could get into CiviCRM > Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs and set "Force Secure URLs (SSL)" to No. Before I did that, there was a proper warning that https was not set up on this machine, but it wasn't the killer I thought. Again, MANY THANKS!